# How to create stackbar chart in raphael js.

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, raphael

How to create stackbar chart in raphael js. I know it in D3js but could not find any way to create it in raphael js. Can some one share some inputs to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Either use [g.raphael](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael) library, or just implement it yourself, all you need is to draw rectangles of different height or width on different positions with labels on them.